# Netbeans Error on $_SERVER

Tags: php, netbeans

I have the following code:

```
<?php
defined('ROOT') or define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
?>
```

Netbeans returns:

```
Do not acces superglobal $_SERVER Array Directly.
```

I recently updated netbeans, in previous versions I didn't have this message, is it safe to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

Print All index of $_SERVER Array BY this code :

```
<?php

    $keyy=array();
//
while(key($_SERVER)){
    array_push($keyy,key($_SERVER));
    next($_SERVER);
}
foreach($keyy as $ke)
echo '<a style="color:red;" >'.$ke.'</a> '.$_SERVER[$ke].' <br>';
?>
```

if Print Errors you don't Access to $_SERVER on this Server...

For security Just Permission to 
 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
  $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] 
 $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
   is enough!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but not the answer i was looking for!

Comment: Yes!Close Access to $_SERVER And some of Functions is Best way to safe Server at Shell's And Attacks. I'm Sorry .My English not Good!!;)

Comment: Give Server Information to Clint's or Server Users . is Dangerous .By define() or $_SERVER